# Download music playlist on Youtube Music with Python

Tags: youtube

*Hello! I'm writing in Portuguese br and translating on google, I'm sorry but I'm still studying basic English.*
**My question is:** I found some ways to download videos from youtube with python and even convert to mp3, but I really want to download songs, playlist...

there is the spotify-dl library that does this but I want to use the youtube music application, I am a subscriber premium but my music playlists don't show up in the video app's playlist group. Did you understand? (laughs) **Thanks in advance!**